# Ypub test vectors missing for mainnet

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, p2sh

Following extended key derivation scheme in BIP49 is there a publicly available test vector repository for mainnet? The test vectors in https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0049.mediawiki#test-vectors are for testnet only.